# Best way to downcast an object to hide low level error

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I have a library that wraps around `pyodbc`. Good design dictates it should hide all knowledge of pyodbc from its clients. This also means that the clients should have to deal with  `mylib.Error` instead of `pyodbc.Error`. On top of that, simply catching `pyodbc.Error` in `mylib` and replacing it with `mylib.Error` is ugly, because the traceback shows cascading exception instead of just one:

> pyodbc.DataError: (...String or binary data would be truncated...')
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last): ...

So the best way to hide the gore details is to cast the exception instead:

```
import pyodbc

class DataTruncated(pyodbc.DataError):
    pass


def execute(sql):
    dbcursor = pyodbc.connect(database="mydb").cursor()
    try:
        dbcursor.execute(sql)

    except pyodbc.Error as e:
        if 'truncated' in  e.args[1]:
            e.__class__ = DataTruncated

        raise
```

Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: If the traceback beyond this point is relevant, that is a sign your library is not abstracting enough. Since you are catching the error, can you just suply enoguh information on what is going on, so that the traceback is not needed at all?

Comment: Also, if you mean to hide pydobc, you _should not_ inherit your exceptions from the pyodbc Exceptions - just create your own Exception hierarchy - possibly just inheriting from Python exceptions that are semantically relevant to your users (ValueError, RuntimeError, etc...)

Comment: @jsbueno pyodbc exception already inherits from Exception, there is no point hiding the inheritance chain since client code should not need it. I did not understand what you meant by traceback not being relevant. Exceptions should always be thrown for the downstream clients to handle them properly, and every exception has a traceback associated with it.